# Issue with root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I everyone !

I have to show that with $r=\frac{p}{q}$ a rationnal number, an $k$ a natural number :

$\exp(i\times\pi\times 2^k \times r)$ is a $2q$-th root of unity.

What I did :

$\exp(i\times\pi\times 2^k \times r)=(e^{i\times\pi})^{2^k \times r}$
$=((e^{i\times\pi})^{2^k})^r$

I used the fact that $e^{i\times\pi}=-1$ and $2^k$ is even :

$((e^{i\times\pi})^{2^k})^r=((-1)^{2^k})^r$
$=1^r=1$

I know there is a mistake somewhere because for $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $k=1$,

$\exp(i\times\pi\times 2^k \times r)=-1$

Can you help me to fix my issue please ?

Comment: $\exp(2i \pi n/m)$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity iff $gcd(m,n)=1$. In general it is a $km$-th root of unity and a primitive $\frac{m}{gcd(m,n)}$-th root of unity.

Comment: What mistake?  -1 is a square root of unity.

Comment: @reuns can you show me the proof of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake lies in assuming that $e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$. This is worst than wrong: it doesn't make sense in general (but it holds if $b\in\mathbb Z$).

You can prove what you wish to prove this way:\begin{align}\exp\left(i\pi2^k r\right)^{2q}&=\exp\left(i\pi 2^k\frac pq\times2q\right)\\&=\exp\left(i\pi 2^{k+1}p\right)\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't make sense in general please ?

Comment: Of course. The number $e^a$ can be any number $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. But then, what is $w^b$? How do you define it?

Comment: I provided an answer to that, did I not?